# Find position of string within list if said string is equal to the given input

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.4

I have written this code to find the position of the word I insert as input.

I inserted existing words, but my code has not located their position. It returns "not found".

```
data=["mama","mia","here","I","go","again"]

inputo= input("word?")

for item in data:
  if item is inputo:
    print (data.index(inputo))
else:
  print("not found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare using `==` instead of `is`. `is` is actually very seldom useful (except for comparing with built-in constants like `None`) because it compares if it's the same object ("reference") while `==` checks for "value equality". So `is` should only be used to compare with a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or you **really know what you're doing**.

However you could just use a `try` and `except` around `data.index` and it should work without any manual iteration and comparisons:

```
try:
    print(data.index(inputo))
except ValueError:
    print('not found')
```

At least as long as there is only one match in the list. In case there could be multiple matches you can use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    if item == inputo:
        print(idx)
else:
    print("not found")
```